# Why data field in FCM Data API is empty?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-analytics

There is some troubles with pushes delivery, so recently we decided to gather FCM Aggregated Delivery Data according to this [post](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/what-is-fcm-aggregated-delivery-data-d6d68396b83b)  and see insights.

1 - I followed steps described in [BigQuery data export](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery?platform=android#bigquery-data-export) and linked project to BigQuery

2 - Then configured android project export to [Enable message delivery data export](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery?platform=android#enable-message-delivery-data-export)

```
...
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context)
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().setDeliveryMetricsExportToBigQuery(true)
...
```

Android project uses in app-module level `build.gradle`

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.0.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
```

After configuring project it started to collect data in BigQuery without `analytics_label`. However the [query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcmdata/rest/v1beta1/projects.androidApps.deliveryData/list) to view aggregated push delivery data were returning empty `data` field:

```
{
  "androidDeliveryData": [
    ...,
    {
      "appId": "...",
      "date": {
        "year": 2022,
        "month": 12,
        "day": 25
      },
      "data": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

Our backend were using legacy API to send data notifications. And we diceded to add `analytics_label` to sending push notification from backend, they said that this field is in new Firebase API v1. Backend team succesfully migrated to `firebase-api-v1` from legacy. And BigQuery were populated with analytics labeled data. According to [limitaions of API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery?platform=android#aggregate-data-timelines) it can take yp to 5 days to be able to see aggregated data. It's been 9 days and I still getting empty data fields.

How can I achive getting aggregated pushes delivery data?